# How to extract last directory in path in Zsh?

Tags: zsh, parameter-expansion

Say I have a variable containing path to a directory (with a trailing slash):

```
dir="path/to/dir/"
```

How can I extract the last directory (i.e. `"dir"`) using Zsh's parameter expansion? I would like to avoid calling external programs (like `sed`).

Answer (score 2):

Parameter expansions in `zsh` can use csh-style history modifiers; in this case, you can use `:t`

> ```
>    t      Remove  all leading pathname components, leaving the tail.  This
>           works like `basename'.
> ```

```
% dir="path/to/dir/"
% print $dir
path/to/dir/
% print $dir:t
dir
```

Answer (score 0):

In Zsh, you can nest [expansions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion). So this works:

```
$ dir="path/to/dir/"
$ echo "${${dir%/}##*/}"
dir
```